# Intelligent string replacement/completion in IDEA 11 Ultimate

Tags: java, intellij-idea

IntellJ IDEA 11 has a bizarre way of replacing / completing the text I insert.

Suppose a string value is "oldXML". When I edit it, IDEA helpfully suggests a value "theOldXML". I happily press enter, to accept the change.

To my surprise, IDEA doesn't **replace** the old value with the new one (like Netbeans, or most IDEs I know); it **prepends** it, so the result would be "theOldXMLoldXML", which is nonsense.

Is it possible to change this behavior?

Comment: If you are using autocompletion (Ctrl+space), this is the normal behaviour, as IntelliJ will try to complete what's before the caret, no matter what's after the caret. Suppose you are trying to add a method call before a variable, you don't want the parameter to be removed (replaced) by the result of your autocompletion.

Comment: I want the exact same behavior as in Netbeans, VisualStudio, ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Tab instead of Enter to choose the suggestion, it'll overwrite the whole identifier then